# Clip lines outside the polygons in QGIS

Tags: qgis, clip, error

I have a line layer (rivers) and a polygon layer (forests). Both files have the same SRS. I want in a new layer clear all the rivers that do not flow through the forest. When I try clip tool, I have this error [image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried ignoring the invalid inputs? There could be only one pesky feature preventing the process. Try that first.

Comment: Seems like your geometry is not rectified, have you tried to clean geometry before processing, otherwise suggestion from @Stella makes sense.